# Executing PHP file via .BAT

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am trying to create an installer by executing a PHP file via a Bat file on windows. The PHP file then imports a DB at some stage along with some other installations.

I have been able to do it with other files but no matter what I do on this particular file it always gives me this error:

.BAT FILE

```
@echo on
"C:\uwamp\bin\php\php-7.0.3\php.exe" -f "C:\Program Files\Asset\install\importdb.php"
pause
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
C:\Program Files\Asset\install>"C:\uwamp\bin\php\php-7.0.3\php.exe" -f "C:\Program Files\Asset\install\importdb.php"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php

$restore_file  = "C:\Program Files\Asset\install\asset.sql";
$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "root";
$database_name = "asset";

$cmd = "mysql -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} < $restore_file";
exec($cmd);
?>
```

The behavior is strange because I have another 2 BAT files running the same code executing different PHP files from the exact same directory.

DIRECTORY:
[image: directory listing]

Comment: is it a SQL or PHP file? $restore_file  = "C:\Program Files\Asset\install\asset.sql";

Comment: I think this is very very [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you even have an additional PHP File? Have you tried [mysql batch mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html)?

Comment: The PHP file imports a DB into MySQL. The problem is PHP is not even executing, i'm getting shown that the file cannot be found

Comment: can you use the absolute path for mysql ?

Comment: @Xatenev well.. I'm trying to create an installer, sadly uWamp doesn't allow mysqli in CLI mode without editing the php.ini file,

Comment: If how you declare that other files are executing as well from same code, same directory there is no reason this one is not executed. Please try to change the file name or substitute the code of one of executing file with the code doesn't. Try either restart uWamp (all services).